# I can't use If Statement inside Foreach Statement

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

Why the if statement inside foreach statement is not working? and my array_search function is also not working, im using yii framework

the if statement should print the brand Name but it prints false, may i know the scenario why the if statement returns me a null value or empty, thank you in advance

```
function getColumnKey($brand_name){
    $columnKey = '';

        $five_up_brands = array('K'=>"Coke",'L'=>"Sprite",'M'=>"Royal");
       array_search($brand_name, $five_up_brands);

       foreach ($five_up_brands as $k => $v) {

            if($v == $brand_name){

                $columnKey = $k;
            }
       }

    return $columnKey;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate about "not working"? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: why not `return array_search($brand_name, $five_up_brands);`

Comment: I don't see how you using `yii` framework is relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to return immediately upon matching the brand name rather than let the loop proceed to the next iteration when the condition will no longer be true.

```
function getColumnKey($brand_name){
    $columnKey = '';

    $five_up_brands = array( 'K'=>"Coke", 'L'=>"Sprite", 'M'=>"Royal" );
    /* what is the point of this - it is not used? */
    #array_search( $brand_name, $five_up_brands );

    foreach( $five_up_brands as $k => $v ) {
        if( $v == $brand_name ){
            return $k;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't matter, you just get the last matched value instead of the first (which in this case is the same).

Answer (score 0):

i just tried this code..

it is working fine. it gives me output like this

> string(1) "L"

```
<?php
    function getColumnKey($brand_name){
       $five_up_brands = array('K'=>"Coke",'L'=>"Sprite",'M'=>"Royal");
       return array_search($brand_name, $five_up_brands);
}
var_dump(getColumnKey('Sprite'));
```

Answer (score 0):

array search will work fine

```
$five_up_brands = array('K'=>"Coke",'L'=>"Sprite",'M'=>"Royal");
$b = array_search("Coke",$five_up_brands);
echo "$b";
```

This worked for me, check it out.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

try this... working code:

```
function getColumnKey($brand_name){

        $five_up_brands = array('K'=>"Coke",'L'=>"Sprite",'M'=>"Royal");

       foreach ($five_up_brands as $k => $v) {

            if($v == $brand_name){

                return $k;
            }
       }

    return false;
}`
```

Comment: The exact same code - with an explanation - was already posted more than 7 minutes ago...